# Is there an accurate way to check status of google's fusion tables platform?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I've been using fusiontables for several months for some web applications (inserting data via query api, and accessing data via google maps api)

As of March 10, Any attempt to insert data to the table, or access the tables via google docs, results in an http 404 response.

The google maps api integration still seems to be pulling information correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to check the status of Fusion Tables, but you can join the announce mailing list: https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-api-announce.

Can you share a link to one of the tables that is resulting in a 404 response?